# How to remove Button from Flex Mobile app actionbar with AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-mobile

How exactly would i remove a Button from the actionBar "actionContent" in a flex mobile app?

I tried these:

```
this.stage.removeChild(menu_btn);
this.removeChild(menu_btn);
stage.removeChild(menu_btn);
this.stage.removeElement(menu_btn);
this.removeElement(menu_btn);
stage.removeElement(menu_btn);
```

I'm not having any luck with those. Im guessing where it is located in the actioncontent isn't considered the stage. Any ideas?

```
<s:actionContent>
        <s:CalloutButton id="menu_btn" icon="@Embed('assets/images/menu/menu_btn.png')" visible="false">
            <s:VGroup>
            <s:Button id="btn_one" label="Button" />
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:CalloutButton>
    </s:actionContent>
```

The actionContent is setup like that, I know like with most mxml stuff I could give it an ID to reference it but im not sure how how to give the action content an id number `<s:actionContent id="testID">` does not work. So how can i access this to remove it? making it invisible isn't cutting it i need to actually remove it.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the question, the removeChild stuff you have tried, if you have a reference to menu_btn, you can always remove it from its parent, like menu_btn.parent.removeChild(menu_btn), without knowing who the parent is, so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being that `actionContent` is a property of the [ActionBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ActionBar.html#actionContent), it already is the "id" of an object, namely an Array.  Try using an `Array` method to remove it.  For instance, you could use `actionContent.pop()` if the thing you want to remove is the last element.  Or use [splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29):

```
actionContent.splice(actionContent.indexOf(menu_btn),1);
```

which will remove the element from the Array.

Comment: awesome. thanks! I was thinking in terms of like a whole "addchild" "removechild" kinda thing. Didn't even think of it like an array.